# getting API response [JSON like] but getting problem while parsing

Tags: reactjs, json, typescript

my API is responding as below

```
{"permissions":
   [{"id":1,"product_id":10,"permission_type":"ADD","name":"Add"}, 
    {"id":2,"product_id":10,"permission_type":"UPDATE","name":"Update"}, 
    {"id":3,"product_id":10,"permission_type":"DELETE","name":"Delete"}
   ]
}
```

when i use code

```
const {
    states: { permissions },
  }:any = useUMSStoreContext();

  const myJSON = JSON.stringify(permissions);
  console.log('JSON format', myJSON)
```

I need to get elements like name or permission_type but not getting success using Typescript. I might be picking wrong way to convert into JSON.

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use stringify, just use the json object

```
  const myJSON = JSON.parse(permissions);
  console.log(myJson[0].permissions[0].name); // removed . typo
```

Simple explanation of format :
https://www.json.org/json-en.html

Comment: const myJSON = JSON.parse(permissions);                                                                
  ---- gives                                         SyntaxError: "[object Object]" is not valid JSON
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Comment: just a typo because fast replied, correct syntax is :     let permissions = '{"permissions":\
   [{"id":1,"product_id":10,"permission_type":"ADD","name":"Add"}, \
    {"id":2,"product_id":10,"permission_type":"UPDATE","name":"Update"}, \
    {"id":3,"product_id":10,"permission_type":"DELETE","name":"Delete"} \
   ] \
  }';
  const myJSON = JSON.parse(permissions);
  console.log(myJSON.permissions[0].name);
  console.log(myJSON.permissions[1].permission_type);

Comment: typescript playground:  https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=9&ssc=54&pln=1&pc=1#code/ATA2FMBdgB3AnAtgSwM6uQewHauAXmAHIBvAIjiTQx1TIC4AdAKBGAG1zkATBgRgA0FeJm4BXAMaQA+j34AGIZRTos2aZACecBmQCCAEQNkh2AIaJwuvd14BfAcBZtgXXvQBMSkeKmz3fIoUCCo06lo69GQAqgAKBnoAKgCiJmTmlrrRMNxmkFYOTqxsbgwAzN6ikjJy9IFKIdRqGtpWUQbJADLJKWkZbWQG4BD5ZHZFbAC6E8B2RADcxRK00IiaAFIAygDyAHIEwFt7AHQwZvCo4AAUyk20AJSLIMu4mBDHoJgA5ldrR7unRqqWjseSTY79R5LWhvcAfb6-DY7AG3YG4dh8cGosItOBQkDFIA